# Prevent scroll beyond div

Tags: javascript, scroll, hover

There are two divs:

## header and #blog.

Scroll page from one to the other occurs after clicking on the (a href="# blog" - down, or a href="# header" - back to top)
I need to prevent scrolling beyond each of these divs (if hover), the transition is carried out only on the links. But I need to leave the scroll inside of them.

Tried this doesn't work:

```
$("#header").hover(function(){
$("body").css("overflow","hidden");});
```

`$("body").hover(function()` - this function works
`$("#header").hover(function()` - this doesn't works

How else I can to implement the idea?

Comment: can you clarify your question, because from this i don't have a clear vision what you're trying to achieve.
Also, adding example code will help the community to help you!

Comment: Yes, can you please post a jsfiddle example for this?